# Content not pushing footer down on page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi my footer is not pushed down by content. I have tried z-index, sticky footers and none have corrected this.

http://www.subsbench.pamelajkeogh.com/player.html

css

```
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:105px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#eaebec;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #eaebec, #7c7d7f);
/*  position: relative;*/
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

html

```
      <!-- Footer -->       
        <div id="footer" class="panel-footer col-xs-12">
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <img id="subsBench-footer-img" src="images/Footer_Black_onTheBench_strapline_and_logo.png" alt="SubsBench Logo and Strapline">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <img id="sm-icons" src="images/social_media_Icons.png" alt="Social Media icons">
          </div>
        </div><!-- /Footer -->

</div><!-- /container -->
```

bootstrap panel-footer

```
.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Where is your footer? Can you show us more details?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `position: absolute;` on your footer, which may be why it's not being "pushed down by content". Have you tried using `position: relative;` at all (it looks like you've commented it out)?

**Resources:**

- [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](https://www.css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning)